# How to query my tables to give data in such a format?

Tags: mysql, sql, orm

I have developed a structure to represent hierarchical data in in my db. Now I have 3 tables with relationship defined with each one. 
[image]

How should I query my db to get the data in such a structure.
[image]

Query I have to get data from separate tables
(Gives me all the users with product in the table)
List discUsersConfs = newArrayList(ao.find(DiscUserConf.class, Query.select()));

(Gives me all the effects with users in the table)

List discEffectConfs = newArrayList(ao.find(DiscEffectConf.class, Query.select()));

How can I combine these queries to get the data in way I have shown the relationship in the below image.
I am using Active Objects which is one of the ORM.

Comment: where is query you have tried ?

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? Where is sample data where is the query you have?

Comment: I just wanted to give the visual representation of what I was trying to achieve. Updating the question with query.

Answer (score 1):

I normally would do it like this.

```
select all from table1
while fetching{
     select again but from table 2 where user = (user from the table1)
          ...and so on..

 }
```

This is a problem and it has more than one solution. The problem with my method is that for each deeper level you must give more table and add them manually to the code